# Ironpython causes Xamarin.Android app to fail compiling

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ironpython

I making an Android app that loads certain python scripts from the user's phone and executes them. I can load the scripts just fine, but the problem is when I compile, I get this error:
`` Can not resolve reference: `Mono.Posix.NETStandard`, referenced by `IronPython`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Mono.Posix.NETStandard`, or remove the reference to `IronPython`. ``

I am using the IronPython Nuget package.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try doing the thing the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Yes, I added Mono.Posix.NETStandard it still gave me the same error.